# Getting the Controller and Action used to call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In a Partial View `_MyView.cshtml` I need to get the *Controller* name and the *Action* used to create the parent calling view.

So if */Equity/Sell* was the *Controller/Action* used to call the view which rendered the partial view `_MyView.cshtml` , then I need the value */Equity/Sell*.

I don't see an object that can do that though.

Comment: What are you using the value for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view use:

```
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

For posterity in a child action it is like this:

```
ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

Comment: Hi , Close, but I'm trying to get it in the .cshtml, not in the Action

Comment: That works in the cshtml - just paste `@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");` somewhere in your partial view and you should see the output.

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com I included the Child Action part as I do both in my applications occasionally (logging, bread crumbs, etc) and found both examples when I searched my code to provide your answer :)